# Cryptographic Shuffle and Pick

Tags: random

I'm implementing a cryptographically secure shuffle routine and have a couple questions:

The method I'm using is a weighted sort where each weight is a cryptographically strong random number.

1. I'm computing the number of bits required for each weight by using the number of items in the list (X) and plugging it into this formula = `log10(X!) / log10(2)`.  For example a 52 card deck would require `log10(52!) / log10(2) = 225.58100312370276194634244437667` bits per weight.  I'm always rounding this up since fractions of a bit cannot be represented.  Am I correct in always rounding up or is that giving me too many bits?
2. Retrieving bits from a hardware rng is perhaps not so practical so bytes must be retrieved.  As in the previous example `226 / 8 = 28.25`, so we have 28 full bytes, and an extra byte to get the remaining 2 bits.  What I'm doing is discarding the unused upper 6 bits of the last byte such that only 2 more bits are appended to the number.  Am I correct in simply discarding these bits or am I destroying the entropy by doing that?
3. I am sorting by the (left padded, all uppercase, ASCII) hexadecimal strings of weights assigned to each number.  This appears to produce the correct sort order.  Are there any catches to sorting strings in this manner that I should be aware of?
4. I should be using a hardware rng which tests the entropy of the numbers it's generating, but I'm stuck using MS RNGCryptoServiceProvider.  Are there better Cryptographic RNG's to use with .NET?
5. To "pick" a number from the cryptographically weighted and sorted list, I'm simply choosing index 0.  Is there a better cryptographically random method of choosing an item in the list?

Let me know if I can help clarify or if this is the wrong site please let me know what a better site would be.

Here's my code if it helps illustrate what I'm talking about VB.NET Console application:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Module Module1

    Public Class Ball
        Public Weight As String
        Public Value As Integer
        Public Sub New(ByVal _Weight As String, ByVal _Value As Integer)
            Weight = _Weight
            Value = _Value
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class BallComparer_Weight
        Implements IComparer(Of Ball)
        Public Function Compare(x As Ball, y As Ball) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Ball).Compare
            If x.Weight > y.Weight Then
                Return 1
            ElseIf x.Weight < y.Weight Then
                Return -1
            Else
                Return 0
            End If
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class BallComparer_Value
        Implements IComparer(Of Ball)
        Public Function Compare(x As Ball, y As Ball) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Ball).Compare
            If x.Value > y.Value Then
                Return 1
            ElseIf x.Value < y.Value Then
                Return -1
            Else
                Return 0
            End If
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Function Weight(ByVal rng As RNGCryptoServiceProvider, ByVal bits As Integer) As String
        ' generate a "cryptographically" random string of length 'bits' (should be using hardware rng)
        Dim remainder As Integer = bits Mod 8
        Dim quotient As Integer = bits \ 8
        Dim byteCount As Integer = quotient + If(remainder <> 0, 1, 0)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = New Byte(byteCount - 1) {}
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        rng.GetBytes(bytes)
        For index As Integer = bytes.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If index = bytes.Length - 1 Then
                ' remove upper `remainder` bits from upper byte
                Dim value As Byte = (bytes(0) << remainder) >> remainder
                result &= value.ToString("X2")
            Else
                result &= bytes(index).ToString("X2")
            End If
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function ContainsValue(ByVal lst As List(Of Ball), ByVal value As Integer) As Boolean
        For i As Integer = 0 To lst.Count - 1
            If lst(i).Value = value Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim valueComparer As New BallComparer_Value()
        Dim weightComparer As New BallComparer_Weight()
        Dim picks As New List(Of Ball)
        Dim balls As New List(Of Ball)
        ' number of bits after each "ball" is drawn
        Dim bits() As Integer = New Integer() {364, 358, 351, 345, 339}

        Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
            While True

                picks.Clear()

                ' simulate random balls
                'log10(75!) / log10(2) = number of bits required for weighted random shuffle (reduces each time ball is pulled) = 363.40103411549404253061653790169 = 364
                For i As Integer = 0 To 4
                    balls.Clear()
                    For value As Integer = 1 To 75
                        ' do not add previous picks
                        If Not ContainsValue(picks, value) Then
                            balls.Add(New Ball(Weight(rng, bits(i)), value))
                        End If
                    Next
                    balls.Sort(weightComparer)

                    'For Each x As Ball In balls
                    '    Console.WriteLine(x.Weight)
                    'Next
                    'Console.ReadLine()

                    ' choose first ball in sorted list
                    picks.Add(balls(0))
                Next
                picks.Sort(valueComparer)

                ' simulate random balls
                'log10(15!) / log10(2) = number of bits required for weighted random shuffle = 40.250140469882621763813506287601 = 41 bits required for megaball
                balls.Clear()
                For value As Integer = 1 To 15
                    balls.Add(New Ball(Weight(rng, 41), value))
                Next
                balls.Sort(weightComparer)

                ' print to stdout
                For i As Integer = 0 To 4
                    Console.Write(picks(i).Value.ToString("D2") & " "c)
                Next
                Console.WriteLine(balls(0).Value.ToString("D2"))

            End While
        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: @D.W. - Ok, thanks, can you move it over there for me?  Where is the "help center"?

Comment: PaintByNumber, if you want to have it migrated there, you can click the "flag" button underneath the question and flag it for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it.  However... I'm not sure whether this question will be well-received on SO in its current form, because it mixes so many different questions together.  I suggest you start with your most critical question, then post one question asking about that narrowly focused question on the appropriate site.  You might also expand on what you're trying to achieve.  The help center is available under the "help" link at the upper right.

Comment: Hey thanks D.W.  I can't flag questions, when I click 'flag' nothing happens.  If you want to flag it that'd be ok.  There's just too much "legalism" with these sites.  Too many rules and restrictions on each site, so might as well close or delete this question.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea seems sound.  However:

- You don't need that many bits in your weights.  All you need is enough to [make collisions unlikely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), i.e. about ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n<sup>2</sup>⌉ bits per item, plus a few for good measure.  For 52 cards, the bare minimum is about 12 bits per card, and 16 bits will get the probability of a collision down to about 4%.  That should be plenty, at least as long as you check for collisions explicitly.
- You *should* check for collisions (i.e. two items having the same random sort key), and restart the shuffle if you find one.  Alternatively, you can increase the length of the sort keys enough to make the probability of getting a collision negligibly small.
- Yes, encoding the sort keys in hexadecimal should be OK.  In fact, it doesn't really matter much *how* you encode them, as long as it's deterministic (i.e. always gives the same encoding for the same random number).  That said, since you know the length of the random bitstrings, why not just store them in raw binary?  (In particular, if you need less than 64 bits per key, you could just store each key in an appropriately sized integer variable.)
- If you want to avoid [side channel attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack), you should choose a sorting method that provably runs in constant time, and with constant power consumption, regardless of what the final order will be.  This is easier said than done, since most common sorting algorithms are nowhere *near* constant time.  That said, depending on your application, such attacks may or may not matter (but don't rule them out before you've thought about the issue!).

An alternative method of securely shuffling an array would be to use a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) with a cryptographically secure RNG.  This method can be less wasteful of bits and easier to implement in constant time (or at least in time independent of the output; see below), but it does require your generator to be able to return unbiased samples from any integer range, not just from ranges with a power-of-two length.  ([Rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is one way to do this — it's not constant-time, but it *can* be shown that the time needed does not reveal anything about the eventual output, so it's still OK.)

Finally, if you only need *one* element from the shuffled array, all of this is unnecessary: just pick a random index to the array (uniformly, e.g. using the rejection sampling method mentioned above) and return the corresponding element.